# Wicket Bookmarkable link

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have created a new link in the Welcome.java as the following

```
private Link<Void> drawLink;

drawLink = new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("drawSome", drawSomething.class);
add(drawLink);
```

The following goes in the Webpage.html

```
<li>
<a href="#" wicket:id="drawSome">Draw</a>           
</li>
```

There are two issues I want to fix.

1. I get the url as

   localhost/project-name/wicket/bookmarkable/package-name.drawSomething?0

but I wanted the link to be as

localhost/project-name/drawSomething?0

1. As the drawSomething is a new page added to the project, like welcome page I am having a drawSomethign.properties file for page.icon and page.title.

   page.title=D3 vis
   page.icon=images/home_page.png

The drawSomething page loads the page title but throws an error for the image as could not resolve images folder.

But I have images folder in src/main/webapp/images/home_page.png

Can anyone please help me resolve both the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this during you application initailization:

```
@Override
protected void initialize() {
    mountPage("drawSomething", drawSomething.class);
}
```

Path to the images folder is relative to webroot path, try `../images/home_page.png`